# What is the difference between "none of ..." and "neither of"?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between the following examples:

> Neither of my teachers are mathematicians.
>
> None of my teachers are mathematicians.

Comment: Doubtless everyone will say that *neither* applies when there are only two choices, but let's not forget [neither fish, flesh, nor good red herring](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neither_fish,_flesh,_nor_good_red_herring). Having said that, I think apart from the fact that it's a bit of a "one-off" idiom, that one only gets by because *nor* can be used when there are more than two alternatives.

Comment: Yes the (prescriptive) "rule" is that neither and nor should only be used for two things. The descriptive view is that the rule might be arbitrary since lots of people were breaking it before it became a rule and lots break it now. But people who like to be careful about the rules observe it and might mark you down if you don't.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Neither - not either - implies that there is a choice of only two.

So "neither of my teachers" is only correct if there are exactly two teachers, "none of my teachers" can be any number

Comment: I don't think any native speaker would use "neither" for more than two (expect by accident, eg adding a third possibility as an afterthought). "None" for only two options is more likely, but still uncommon, I think.

Comment: @Colin - isn't that what I said?

Comment: Probably you could say **None of my teachers** even if the number of teachers is unknown, if you have only one teacher, or if you have no teachers at all.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: No, you used the word "correct".

Comment: Yes so neither is ONLY correct in the case of two, it's incorrect if there are more. But not that neither is the only correct answer in the case of two.

Answer (score 9):

The distinction already made between two and more than two is valid, but it would be preferable to write the sentences as *Neither / None of my teachers is a mathematician*.

Comment: @GEdgar: In this case,yes, but in other contexts 'none', at least, can be followed by a plural verb.

Answer (score 2):

*Neither* is typically used to mean "not one or the other of two". In order to refer to "none of several", *none* is preferred.