# Using "neither of which"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “none of …” and “neither of”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50693/what-is-the-difference-between-none-of-and-neither-of)

Would it be correct to say *neither of which*? For example,

> The essay contains many well-known facts and some theories based on
>   years of research, **neither of which** would be grounds for
>   copyright.

Comment: ...I assume you're asking whether you can validly use *neither* to simultaneously rule out *more than two factors* ("many facts", ***plus*** "some theories", obviously adds up to a lot more than two things being excluded). But I would also add that *"grounds for copyright"* seems a bit "loose" to me. Do you mean the article doesn't infringe any existing copyrights, or that it can't be copyrighted itself?

Comment: You're linking and denying two **Noun Phrases**, so _neither_ does the job. However, in print, you have to indicate the intonation that divides the NPs; I'd suggest a comma after _facts_ and a period after _research_. The new sentence can start _Neither of which_ or _Neither of these_, as you please.

Comment: @John Lawler: How do OP's "two noun phrases" differ from, for example, *"There were several American men and a few Canadian women at the party, **neither of which** actually spoke to me"*? I can see things getting a little "easier on the ear" if you start a new sentence with *"Neither of **these**..."*, but to avoid it grating at all I'd want to hear something more like *"Neither of **these groups of people**..."*

Comment: I would too. But one can't correct everything in a comment.

Comment: This is the usual and accepted structure in STM writing and is both grammatical and readable as it is. There's no valid reason for the question. Voting to close.

Comment: Thank you for the help. @John Lawler answered my question. And yes, Jasper, I was having doubts about the use of "which". I knew "neither" to be the correct word to deny the two noun phrases. I think Lawler's suggestion to split it into two sentences is best.